# Similar case in switch with little differences

Tags: java, nested, case

I want to execute a switch case where the case's body is similar with another's.
I split the two cases and the editor informed that it is a similar case with another one and had the option of merging with the other. When I did the first case was:

```
...
case 3: {
   case 7:
      System.out.println("Print something: ");
   ...
}
```

However, I want at the case of 3 to print a different message than the one at case 7.

```
...
case 3: {
   System.out.println("Print something different");
   case 7:
      System.out.println("Print something: ");
   ...
}
```

But, when case 3 is executing both messages are printed, whereas when case is 7 only the message of case 7 is printed.
Is there any way to print only the 3rd's when case is 3?

Comment: With break under print statement of case 3, results in not executing the body under those lines. So it will only print "Print something different"

Comment: Extract the common (repeated) code to a method and call it inside the `case`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the two cases (3 and 7) to perform common logic, with the only difference being the printed output, you can add a condition:

```
case 3:
case 7: {
   System.out.println(v == 3 ? "something" : "something else");
   ... common code that should run for both 3 and 7 cases ...
}
```

Where `v` is the switch statement variable.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I thought I tried that but the switch statement variable was a function called, so I had to now store it first.

Comment: Beautiful, this pulls it off

Answer (score 1):

> I want the body of 3 and 7 to be the same, thus executing for both 3 and 7, but when the case is 3, print only the first message and not the one of case 7 too..

```
String stuff ="";

switch (test){
   case 7: stuff = "something Else.\n";  //flow down to 3
   case 3: stuff = "print something.\n" + stuff;  //prepend with print something.
           break;
}

System.out.print(stuff);
```

That said... this way of coding is not really intuitive for the coder. you are better off just separating both cases with a break.

```
String stuff ="";

switch (test){
   case 7: stuff = "something Else.";   
           break;
   case 3: stuff = "print something.\nsomething Else.";   
           break;
}

System.out.println(stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

After each statement, add a break. Otherwise, it will execute both.

```
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Print something different");
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Print something: ");
            break;
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. If I use break the rest of the case 3 won't be executed when case is 3.
Sorry if I wasn't clear; I want the body of 3 and 7 to be the same, thus executing for both 3 and 7, but when the case is 3, print only the first message and not the one of case 7 too..

Comment: Nope. The 2 prints showing there; one is for when case is 3 and the other for when case is 7. The body of both cases is the same, which will be under the lines I wrote. But when case is 3, only the printing under case 3: must be printed, but both are now.

Comment: @DemetrisShimitras It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. It is either case 3 or 7. It can't be both.

Comment: I believe the code provided by @Eran achieves what you need.